# Passing data to another view from controller and set a label's value in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a controller, and I want to pass a simple string value to the next View.

For that, I am creating the View like this.

```
var nextView = Ext.create('MyApp.view.NextView', {
    content: 'value'
});
Ext.Viewport.add(nextView);
Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(nextView, {
    type: 'slide',
    direction: 'left'
});
```

On the **NextView**, I have a label and I want to set the `HTML` property of the label to the value that I am passing from the controller. ie. `value`.

My **NextView** looks like this.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.NextView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        content: 'null',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'label',
            html: 'value'
        }]
    }
});
```

I am not sure how to proceed from here. I can't have the NextView as a form. I just need to pass one string value in this situation.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `initialize` method to access config data like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.NextView', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    config: {
        content: 'null',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'label',
                html: 'value'
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize : function(){
        this.callParent();
        var val = this.config.content;
        this.down('label').setHtml(val);
    }
});
```

*PS* Feel free to use your favourite selector in `down` function

Answer (score 4):

I know the question has been answered. But I just digged up a pretty natural way to pass data from controller to a view (using view's constructor). I use this in my integration of web desktop to my app.

In controller, pass data to the constructor of the view as followed:

```
loiTab = Ext.create('Iip.view.giips.admission.DetailedLoiTab', {closable: true, selectedLoiData: selected[0].data});
```

In the view, spin up a constructor as followed:

```
constructor: function(selectedLoiData) {
    Ext.applyIf(this, selectedLoiData);
    this.callParent();
},
```

The following method lives in the same file as the constructor. You can access selectedLoiData from any where in the view the constructor lives as followed:

```
initComponent: function(){
    console.log(this.selectedLoiData);
}
```